# How is it getting an instantiation error and how to fix it? [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have been coding a simple android Java program, so far I included an `ImageView`, button and an `EditText` in the `activity_main.xml`. However, when I run it, with this `MainActivity` java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
private EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        }
    });

}
```

is not working and it returns a fatal error I cannot resolve. It says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo, java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move these initializations to `onCreate` :

```
private Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
private EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);
```

i.e :

```
private Button start;
private EditText nameField;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        }
    });
}
```

When you call `findViewById(R.id.start)` in the member initialization expression, the `Activity` instance is not initialized yet, which causes the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Wow! ;) Thanks so much! How did that solve everything though?

Comment: @Muymuy1 Once your `onCreate` method is called, the Activity instance is alrady initialized, so you can call `findViewById(R.id.start)` safely.